# How can I apply a style to a Bootstrap React element?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

The following is a line rendered inside a ReactJS Component for my application and saved as `nav.jsx`.

```
<span style="font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;">&nbsp;Home</span>
```

Exception:

```
Uncaught Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX. This DOM node was rendered by `Nav`.
    at invariant (react.js:18354)
    at assertValidProps (react.js:6435)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (react.js:6678)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.js:12978)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (react.js:11692)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (react.js:6815)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (react.js:6703)
    at Object.mountComponent (react.js:12978)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (react.js:11692)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (react.js:6815)
```

Why is this happening and how can I apply the font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error states how to fix this:

> Uncaught Error: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. **For example, `style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}}` when using JSX. This DOM node was rendered by `Nav`.**

The `style` prop for elements expects an object that has keys and values corresponding to CSS properties and their values:

```
<span style={{fontFamily: "'Open Sans', 'sans-serif'"}}>&nbsp;Home</span>
```

Remember that property keys cannot contain `-` and that React camelCases CSS property names, so `font-family` becomes `fontFamily`.

---

As a side note: I would prefer an object declared outside the JSX, so that isn't inline and it's more organized (in my opinion). Another way would be just to use a CSS stylesheet instead of styles in JavaScript.